# OpenGL - What to do so that 1 point is equal to 1pixel

Tags: vb.net, opengl, 3d, gdi+, opentk

I am trying to make a gdi+ to opengl translator(coz gdi+ is v.slow), but I have no idea of what to do so that primitives drawn match the actual screen coordinates(like in gdi+). Without this feature, it will be useless, as porting will be very difficult. I am currently using openTK in vb.net.
eg-

```
GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Lines)
    GL.Vertex2(0, 0)
    GL.Vertex2(100, 0)
GL.End()
```

renders a line far longer that 100px.The perspective settings are:

```
    Dim perspective As Matrix4 = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(1, Width / Height, 1, 10000)
    Dim lookat As Matrix4 = Matrix4.LookAt(0, 0, 225, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
```

Z of eye is set to 255 as it gives pixel accurate measurements but only in the centre of the screen. As we move further, it's not accurate at all. I think that I need to make the surface spherical, so that every point on it is at the same distance, but don't know how to do that.

Below is a sample picture. The rectangle below the line is of 100px(gdi+) and the line is made using the above code(gl).
[Please open this link to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUxrB.png)

Comment: Shouldn't you be using an orthographic projection when rendering 2d things? The length will otherwise depend on the z-value and the opening angle.

Answer (score 1):

BDL is right, first, we need to get the projection matrix. If you are using old openGL (which you shouldn't!), you can call:

```
glOrtho(0, window_width, 0, window_height, -1, 1);
```

where window_width and window_height are expressed in pixels. 
To store this in a matrix you can do:

```
glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection_matrix);
```

Then when you draw your vertices, coordinates can be expressed as:

```
glVertex2i(pX,  pY);
glVertex2i(pX + 100,  pY);
```

This will draw a 100 pixel line starting at (pX,pY). 
(please note this does not use vbo's etc.., I used these calls to illustrate easily)

If you are using modern openGL, just calculate that projection matrix and pass it to your shader. To calculate the projection matrix manually, you can follow this guide:

http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html

Comment: Thank you, I used the orthographic projection in a slightly different way, as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477367/how-to-use-gl-ortho-in-opentk-correctly in the last post.

Comment: But, what if I want to implement 3D like raised rects or blocks with real shadows? Like in android. Ortho is out of the question. Any ideas?

Comment: This (orthographic projection) is exactly what you would use to create the games you are describing "on Android". You would use this projection, with a normal camera modelview matrix, then supply vertices in 3D world coordinates like you would in any normal 3D game. All you are changing when you specify a projection matrix is the way these 3D vertices are "projected" onto the viewport.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, I figured that if you load a perspective matrix during the rendering to render 3D it works.And then again switch to ortho for 2d. Note that I was not talking about game dev. This is mainly for creating fast ui. You know- animations and stuff.